# What does it mean to call std::vector::reserve with no arguments, and why do so after creating an empty vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I was following [this tutorial on move semantics](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html) when I came across something I had never seen before: vector.reserve() with no arguments.  I went to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) for the method yet there is no reserve(void) signature.  If we can call reserve(void), why is it not documented?  Further, what does the call do, and why would we make the call after instantiating an empty vector?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<int> doubleValues (const vector<int>& v)
{
    vector<int> new_values;
    new_values.reserve();
    for (auto itr = v.begin(), end_itr = v.end(); itr != end_itr; ++itr )
    {
        new_values.push_back( 2 * *itr );
    }
    return new_values;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
    {
        v.push_back( i );
    }
    v = doubleValues( v );
}
```

Comment: Good question indeed, especially since there's no [overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) which takes no arguments.

Comment: A typo in the tutorial? Try getting it to compile.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo in some website

Comment: It can't be compiled with g++.

Comment: Ah, well thanks.  As somebody learning C++ I lean on well respected authors to write complete and trustworthy code.  I decided to ask because perhaps there was something I was missing... but alas, just a typo.  I will let the author know.  Until it's fixed, another newcomer to C++ may come across the same tutorial and ask the same question, so maybe my question will serve purpose.

Comment: One important point: the tutorial seems to suggest the code is bad C++03 because it makes unnecessary copies. This is the kind of misleading stuff that makes people scared of returning by value. It would be challenging to find a modern compiler on, say, an ia32 or x86_64 that *doesn't* perform return value optimization in this case. Note: most of that guy's stuff is OK, this is an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the unincluded header, the code doesn't compile, that is, in accordance to the C++11 standard: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ba7ec853fced363

Quoting from the C++11 standard:

> #### § 23.3.6.1 Class template vector overview [vector.overview]

```
[...]
bool empty() const noexcept;
void reserve(size_type n);
void shrink_to_fit();
[...]
```

Always test second-hand code first!

Comment: This is a great answer because it offers a suggestion on what to do if a beginner spots something uncanny -- try to compile it to see if it agrees with the standard :)

Comment: @jakeliquorblues the caveat being that a compiler may accept some illegal code, or not accept legal one (the former case is more common). But it is good to try, nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is merely an error. An instruction of the form:

```
new_values.reserve(v.size());
```

would make perfect sense in this context.

There is no `std::vector::reserve()` in the standard.

Comment: Another possible error: In the first `for` loop, do you think `end_itr = v.end();` should really be `auto end_itr = v.end();`

Comment: @jakeliquorblues are you trying to point all errors on that website? It just shows about the author

Comment: Also, the missing `#include <vector>`. And the suggestion that RVO won't happen in the code. Nevermind... :-)

Comment: @jakeliquorblues `auto x = 1, y = 2;` compiles. `auto x = 1; auto y = 2;` also compiles (in other contexts). `auto x = 1, auto y = 2;` doesn't. That part is right.

Comment: @BЈовић no I'm trying to learn C++

Comment: @jakeliquorblues Then find a good book, and avoid such bogus tutorials.